# How to render a video in Photoshop with transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, adobe-photoshop-elements

I am making an animation in Photoshop that I am then going to use in Sony Vegas. My animation has a transparent background and I am wondering if there's any way to render my animation from Photoshop that will allow me to place it on top of another one inside Vegas and maintain its transparency.

Comment: I suggest rendering it as PNG sequences. That way you keep Transparency and dont loose anything because of compression etc.

Answer (score 5):

- File > Export > Render Video
- Change the format to Quicktime (might be AVI if on Windows)
- In the Alpha Channel, select Straight - Unmatted
- Render

[image]

Comment: I just tried doing this... and it still renders with a black background.

Comment: @AmyStanec did you open the exported file in a video editing program? You won't see transparency in a regular video player.